# InkWell disappears after a second

Tags: flutter

I have an `InkWell()` with just an `onTap` parameter, but the `splash` doesn't stay and disappears after about a second.

**Dart Pad Showing The Problem:** https://dartpad.dev/?id=6a4351b45d48f89f851f4969e4134a9a&null_safety=true

**Screen Recording:** https://cln.sh/2isf6T

**Code:**

```dart
class PageIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  final Function() onTap;
  final IconData icon;
  final bool selected;
  final bool expanded;
  final String label;
  final String? tooltip;
  final double height, width;

  final Color selectedColor, unselectedColor;

  PageIcon({
    Key? key,
    required this.onTap,
    required this.icon,
    required this.selected,
    required this.expanded,
    required this.label,
    required this.height,
    required this.width,
  })  : selectedColor = Colors.blue,
        unselectedColor = Colors.grey[600]!,
        tooltip = null,
        super(key: key);

  PageIcon.tooltip({
    Key? key,
    required this.onTap,
    required this.icon,
    required this.selected,
    required this.expanded,
    required this.label,
    required this.tooltip,
    required this.height,
    required this.width,
  })  : selectedColor = Colors.blue,
        unselectedColor = Colors.grey[600]!,
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget body = SizedBox(
      height: height,
      width: width,
      child: Material(
        color: Colors.transparent,
        child: InkWell(
          mouseCursor: SystemMouseCursors.click,
          onTap: onTap,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Icon(
                icon,
                size: 34,
                color: selected ? selectedColor : unselectedColor,
              ),
              SizedBox(width: expanded ? 10 : 0),
              expanded
                  ? Text(
                      label,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: selected ? selectedColor : unselectedColor,
                        fontSize: 20,
                        fontWeight:
                            selected ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal,
                      ),
                    )
                  : const SizedBox(height: 0, width: 0),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );

    if (tooltip != null) {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
        child: Tooltip(
          message: tooltip!,
          textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.white),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
          child: body,
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
        child: body,
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, it is splash behavior, you want to change color of button, it starts animation from `tapDown` i think, you can check `InteractiveInkFeatureFactory`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh, I already tried changing the `InteractiveInkFeatureFactory` and it didn't work. The behaviour seen is not the default behaviour of the `InkWell()` as I created another `Widget` to be used in a different place in my app and it worked fine. The problem is specific to the code of the `PageIcon()`.

Comment: Been investigating a bit. I think it can be reproduced by using a regular `IconButton` as well. After a long press when the tooltip pops up, the `_handleTapCancel` method of the `InkWell` is called, which cancels and clears the current splash.

Comment: @TimKlingeleers I have encountered that problem before. I also found out that setting an `onLongPress` causes the same issue. However, I only set the `onTap` parameter which is why I'm confused as the `InkWell()` should keep the splash for as long as it is pressed.